# Navigation bar with CSS table-layout property (problems with table-cell and table-row)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive navigation bar that has undetermined number of links on the left side and a search button on the right side.

Links should be equal width no matter how many, and search button should be 50px wide. Responsive comes into play when screen width is less than 768px.

I'm using CSS `table-layout: fixed` as well `table-cell` and `table-row` properties, depending on screen width.

However, Firefox and Chrome seems to do alright but somehow Safari messes up with those equal width elements when switching back and forth the wide and narrow screen (ie. elements are first `table-cells` then `table-rows` and then back again `table-cells`).

Does anyone how to fix this or maybe come up with better design? Or is this just a Safari 6.0.2 bug?

**JSFiddle Demo**
[found here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Wtr/1/).

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need javascript for that

i just added a **:hover** for form width and another **:hover** for input, and it fixes the problem on safari, which when you hover text input, form gets 50px width again (if thats what your problem was)

```
#searchform:hover {
width:250px;
}

#searchform:hover input#s {
display: inline;
}
```

Try my edit in jsfiddle

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Wtr/9/)

Comment: my problem isn't with form. That JS code isn't relevant. And thus, your code doesn't solve the initial problem which was that if you resize the JS HTML output frame sideways back and forth so that list elements got table-cell and table-row values, the layout gets messy. Try it with your demo, for instance, still the same effect.